# How to partition a MySQL table based on char column?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Is it  possible to partition based on char column?

After reviewing the MySQL 5.1 documentation it appears that only integer types can be used.

Is this correct?  Or can  I use some function to convert the char into an integer?

The  char field in question contains a unique identifier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Partitioning in MySQL 5.1 can only deal with integer columns ([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html)). You can only use a [few partitioning functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html) on non-integer columns. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE ti (id INT, amount DECIMAL(7,2), tr_date DATE)
   ENGINE=INNODB
   PARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(tr_date) )
   PARTITIONS 6;
```

You can also use [key partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-key.html) in MySQL 5.1, as long as the primary key includes all the columns in the table's partitioning function:

```
CREATE TABLE k1 (
   id CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   value int
)
PARTITION BY KEY(id)
PARTITIONS 10;
```

On the other hand, in MySQL 5.5, you can use [range column partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-range.html) or [list column partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-list.html) on a wide variety of data types, including character-based columns.

List Columns Example:

```
CREATE TABLE expenses (
   expense_date DATE NOT NULL,
   category VARCHAR(30),
   amount DECIMAL (10,3)
);

ALTER TABLE expenses
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS (category)
(
   PARTITION p01 VALUES IN ('lodging', 'food'),
   PARTITION p02 VALUES IN ('flights', 'ground transportation'),
   PARTITION p03 VALUES IN ('leisure', 'customer entertainment'),
   PARTITION p04 VALUES IN ('communications'),
   PARTITION p05 VALUES IN ('fees')
);
```

Range Columns Example:

```
CREATE TABLE range_test (
   code CHAR(3),
   value INT
)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(code) (
   PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('MMM'),
   PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('ZZZ')
);
```

Further reading:

- [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: Key partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-key.html)
- [A deep look at MySQL 5.5 partitioning enhancements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html)
- [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: Range columns partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-range.html)
- [MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: List columns partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-list.html)

Comment: Thanks - I was looking mostly at HASH/LIST.

Answer (score 0):

What do you hope to gain by PARTITIONing?  HASH and LIST are unlikely to provide any performance gain.  It is rarely useful to partition a table with less than a million rows.

Other comments on partitioning:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

5.6 and 5.7 have relaxed *some* of the restrictions mention in the other answers, but still partitioning is rarely better than indexing.