# Best approach for archiving annual data in mysql db

Tags: mysql

I have a huge amount of data that is generated over the period of an year spanning across many tables. However, keeping all this data in the same tables over the years is making queries slower. While I want to preserve the old data for the purpose of maintaining records and for some end user queries,  they become less relevant when a new calendar year starts. Earlier, I had tried having a archive table for each such table where I would store data that was older than 1 year but this approach causes the archive table to grow pretty big in a small time.

Would it be better to have separate tables altogether for every new calendar year ? i.e.

```
myTable_2011
myTable_2012
myTable_2013
myTable_2014
...
```

thanks

Comment: What do your queries look like that are performing so slowly? Do you need the old data as often as the new data (you could create an "archive" table.) Have you properly set up your tables with a Primary Key?

Comment: They are usually joins spanning 2-3 tables. All of them get over thousand records added every year. Yes all of my tables have integer id primary key's defined.

Comment: The old data is not needed as often but needed nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

You might use partitions. Maybe these links can give you an idea:

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/partitioning.html

[How to partition a MySQL table based on char column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753317/how-to-partition-a-mysql-table-based-on-char-column)

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/database-partitioning

Regards