# two column table partition in hive

Tags: hive, subquery, hiveql

i have a table with two columns

```
  id   value
 abc    11
 xyz    12
 pqr    11
 mno    13 
 pqr    12
 stu    13
 wxy    11
```

i have to partition this table with "value" by hive or sql queries.

Comment: i got some document for table partition in hive but it's not working for two column table.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table1 PARTITION BY KEY(id,value) PARTITIONS 2;`

Comment: @Dev.Joel error  `ParseException line 1:21 cannot recognize input near 'PARTITION' 'BY' 'KEY' in alter table statement (state=42000,code=40000)`

Comment: still same `ParseException line 1:21 cannot recognize input near 'PARTITION' 'BY' '(' in alter table statement (state=42000,code=40000)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753317/how-to-partition-a-mysql-table-based-on-char-column

Comment: @Dev.Joel I don't think this is a mysql question at all. Hadoop. I removed some tags. Feed them back in anyone if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;


create table table (id string) partitioned by (value string) stored as ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY");

INSERT INTO table1 PARTITION (value)
select * from table where value is not NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

after explore it i got the ans.

```
create table table (id string) partitioned by (value string) stored as ORC tblproperties ("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY");


SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;

SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=2048;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=256;

INSERT INTO table1 PARTITION (value)
select * from table where value is not NULL;
```

Comment: it's taking to much memory, Still anyone have better solution so please give it

Comment: remove this two property `SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=2048;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=256` this is not required.